# Find the area of the shaded region in the diagram, in terms of $\theta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, area, rectangles

**Problem**
A company is designing a new logo. The logo is created by removing two equal segments from a rectangle, as shown in the following diagram
[image]

The rectangle measures $5cm$ by $4cm$. The points $A$ and $B$ lie on the circle, with center $O$ and radius $2cm$ such that $\angle AOB=\theta$ where $0<\theta<\pi$, as shown here
[image]

- Find the area of one of the shaded segments [in pink] in terms of $\theta$.
- Given that area of the logo is $13.4 cm^2$, find the value of $\theta$.

**My Approach**
I have calculated the area in terms of $\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ but don't know how to solve for $\theta$ afterwards. There must be way to find the area of the removed segment without $\sin\theta$ and $\theta$. Can someone please guide for the same?

Comment: I don't think this will have a nice algebraic solution. We'd need to find a root by computer (or painstaking Newton's method etc.).

Comment: Segment area is difference of sector area and triangle area. Both of them can be expressed in terms of $\theta$. For second part one need to solve transcendental equation $S(\theta)=\frac{20-13.4}{2}$. Equation is transcendental because $S(\theta)$ contains both linear and trigonometric summands. Transcendental equation can be solved by plotting or by numerical methods. Answer is approximately 135.03°. First approximation for answer can be obtained using Taylor expansion of sine around $\theta=0$ but it is too rough: 123°.

Answer (score 1):

[image: logo]

Working in radians, sector $AOB=\frac{\pi r^2\theta}{2\pi}=2\theta$

And since $\sin (2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, and radius $OA=2$, then

$\triangle AOB=\frac{1}{2}AB \cdot OC=AC \cdot OC=4\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=2\sin\theta$

Hence the $3.3\mathrm{cm^2}$ segment, expressed in terms of $\theta$ is$$2\theta-2\sin\theta$$And consulting a trigonometric table or calculator (if that is allowed here) shows that $2\theta-2\sin\theta=3.298$ for $\theta=135^o=2.356194\mathrm{rad}$

Answer (score 0):

This can only be solved using a graphing tool which is allowed on the exam that this question was asked. The answer to this is $\theta = 135.05^{\circ}$